# Could be $(x_n)_n $ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)_n $ such that $\displaystyle\frac {2018}{x_n} =\left(\frac {x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)^{(n+1)/2}$, $\forall n\geq 1$.

I have to study the convergence of the sequence.

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Any info about $x_1$?

Comment: It might help to try rewriting the recursion relation.

Comment: Can you solve for $x_{n+1}$?  What do the first few terms look like?  When you don't know where to start, calculate a few terms to get some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_n=x_n^n$. Then the recursion is equivalent to
$$y_{n+1}=2018^2y_n. $$
Find a closed form for $y_n$ in terms of $y_0$ from this and draw conclusions about $x_n$.